# Using GWT and CSS, how to flip vertically all the letter at even positions in input element?

Tags: html, css, gwt, input, flip

I use GWT. I need to flip vertically all the letter at even positions while keeping the letters at the odd positions intact in element. Now I'm using this css style: -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg). But it flips the whole text in input element.

How it can be implemented using GWT and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You only can rotate all the text matching a css selector.

Because there is no way to select an individual letter using css, the only way to rotate even letters is wrapping them with spam (or other tag).